# What is a “capstone track” in a Master’s program?

Tags: united-states

I've read in [this other question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11310/2700):

> The Master's program (Software Engineering) I'm enrolled in offers both a thesis track and capstone track.

I'm somewhat familiar with the overall US academic system, but I've never heard of a “capstone track” before. I web-searched it, and found quite a few institutions that offer it, it seems a sort of more practice-oriented or business-oriented way of completing a given degree. It does not appear to be universal.

So: **what is a “capstone track” in general, and how is it different from a Master of Engineering degree?**

Comment: I believe it means that, in lieu of a thesis, you will complete a capstone project. That capstone would be less research-oriented than a thesis, and more like a significantly-sized project.

Comment: @J.R. sorry if I am slow witted, but defining “capstone track” by “capstone project” doesn't help me much… I imagine it is some sort of “achievement”, a figurative use of the archaeologic vocabulary, but other than that I don't see how it differs from a thesis

Comment: A thesis solves an unsolved problem. It requires extensive background research to determine the current state of knowledge, a well-defined problem that will expand that knowledge, and a plan of attack for how to go about that expansion. On the other hand, a capstone is more hands-on; in a software engineering program, it would probably revolve around building some software system. Capstones are less theoretical than a thesis, and more likely to result in a system people might actually use. Both can involve a lot of time and effort, but the capstone is more applied, the thesis more theoretical.

Comment: Put another way, a thesis might offer hard evidence that one approach to solving a problem is better than another, substantiated with hard data and a lot of testing. A capstone project simply solves a problem with little regard to the "bigger picture" – it is less abstract. At the end of a thesis, the author might conclude, "Our research shows that Methodology X is a good way to test embedded systems." At the end of a capstone, the author might write, "We successfully used Method X to test Embedded System Y." The end goals are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many software engineering programs offer the option of a "capstone" software project instead of a thesis to complete the degree.  This is typically a project that stretches over a full semester, or year, or even longer.  In my department, these projects are designed in cooperation with local industry, so there are real "customers". The  intention is that the project will force the student to synthesize all the skills and knowledge acquired in other classes in the program, and will give them something closer to real-world experience that a typical class project.

As for "how is this different from a Master of Engineering", I have no idea.  Everybody gives their degrees different names; there is no standard. (My department offers a capstone project only for undergrads; the degree is a Bachelor of Science whether you do the project or not.)